# Noticed updating taxonomy terms take a long time and run out of memory

Tags: taxonomy, memory

Not sure if it's related to 5.5, that is what we're running. But if we go to edit a taxonomy term (say... update the description). It's been taking a long time. Some investigation reveals that it's associated with the number of posts associated with the term, about a second per 1,000 posts. And if I have a term with more than like... 40,000 associated posts, after a minute of loading, I get the "There has been a critical error on your website" error. Investigating that revealed that it ran out of memory.

Increasing the memory to 512MB "fixed" the problem. But it really feels like when the task is "Add a period to the end of that taxonomy term description"... to require 512MB to do that seems excessive.

Has anyone else seen anything like this?

Comment: You are sure you don't have anything hooked into the term updates?

Comment: @vancoder don't think so.  I disabled most of the plug-ins that I thought might have something to do with it, but no luck.  Is there any keyword/phrase I can search for in the theme and plug-ins folders that would be match a term update hook?

Comment: `edited_terms` or `edited_{$taxonomy}` perhaps.